# How to print contents of classes in a website with requests and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to write code that will print the first 5 listings and their price(platinum) from this site https://warframe.market/items/ember_prime_set
and upon inspection of the page i found that the numbers I'm interested in are in "orders-row__element order__price sell_color" classes how would i go about printing the contents of that class in text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Site uses render from json object. You can easily find object inside the html document.

**Simplified code example:**

```
import json

from re import search
from pprint import pprint

from requests import Session

session = Session()
session.headers['user-agent'] = (
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) '
    'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/'
    '66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36'
)

limit = 5
url = 'https://warframe.market/items/ember_prime_set'

response = session.get(url=url)

res = search(
    pattern='<script type="application/json" id="application-state">(.*?)</script>',
    string=response.text
)

items = json.loads(res.group(1))
items = reversed(items['payload']['orders'])

for i, raw in enumerate(items):
    print('#', i,'*' * 40)
    print('Name', raw['user']['ingame_name'])
    print('Status', raw['user']['status'])
    print('platinum', raw['platinum'])
    print('*' * 40)
    print('RAW Document')
    print('*' * 40)
    pprint(raw)
    print('*' * 40)

    if i >= limit:
        break
```

**Result:**

```
# 0 ****************************************
Name afinkidayer
Status ingame
platinum 165
****************************************
RAW Document
****************************************
{'creation_date': 'iso',
 'id': '5b12e102c34b9200bbea34c2',
 'last_update': 'iso',
 'order_type': 'sell',
 'platform': 'pc',
 'platinum': 165,
 'quantity': 1,
 'region': 'en',
 'user': {'avatar': 'user/avatar/5a6b4b1f0a0674021a93262f.png?a2e235b2c1bfe9cc9a85128b5f5c1fc6',
          'id': '5a6b4b1f0a0674021a93262f',
          'ingame_name': 'afinkidayer',
          'last_seen': '2018-06-02T18:11:33.142000+00:00',
          'region': 'en',
          'reputation': 3,
          'reputation_bonus': 0,
          'status': 'ingame'},
 'visible': True}
****************************************
# 1 ****************************************
Name Guzamuza
Status ingame
platinum 160
****************************************
RAW Document
****************************************
{'creation_date': 'iso',
 'id': '5b12e0ad3048b200ba93ae28',
 'last_update': 'iso',
 'order_type': 'sell',
 'platform': 'pc',
 'platinum': 160,
 'quantity': 1,
 'region': 'en',
 'user': {'avatar': 'user/avatar/5aba587312434f04f4800b19.png?db332ade3ee5f86a7a8f417167250cfd',
          'id': '5aba587312434f04f4800b19',
          'ingame_name': 'Guzamuza',
          'last_seen': '2018-06-02T17:50:59.343000+00:00',
          'region': 'en',
          'reputation': 0,
          'reputation_bonus': 0,
          'status': 'ingame'},
 'visible': True}
****************************************
# 2 ****************************************
Name Sirfol
Status ingame
platinum 170
****************************************
RAW Document
****************************************
{'creation_date': 'iso',
 'id': '5b12de9d383eea00a8bad513',
 'last_update': 'iso',
 'order_type': 'sell',
 'platform': 'pc',
 'platinum': 170,
 'quantity': 1,
 'region': 'en',
 'user': {'avatar': None,
          'id': '577a4c7a0f31390346f2a25a',
          'ingame_name': 'Sirfol',
          'last_seen': '2018-06-02T18:11:42.771000+00:00',
          'region': 'en',
          'reputation': 0,
          'reputation_bonus': 0,
          'status': 'ingame'},
 'visible': True}
****************************************
# 3 ****************************************
Name Wanderous
Status ingame
platinum 180
****************************************
RAW Document
****************************************
{'creation_date': 'iso',
 'id': '5b12dd6dffe75600b3f40393',
 'last_update': 'iso',
 'order_type': 'sell',
 'platform': 'pc',
 'platinum': 180,
 'quantity': 1,
 'region': 'en',
 'user': {'avatar': None,
          'id': '5a611023f629d700dfdbf869',
          'ingame_name': 'Wanderous',
          'last_seen': '2018-06-02T18:09:59.258000+00:00',
          'region': 'en',
          'reputation': 12,
          'reputation_bonus': 0,
          'status': 'ingame'},
 'visible': True}
****************************************
# 4 ****************************************
Name CurryWaffle
Status ingame
platinum 185
****************************************
RAW Document
****************************************
{'creation_date': 'iso',
 'id': '5b12dd27c34b9200bbea349b',
 'last_update': 'iso',
 'order_type': 'sell',
 'platform': 'pc',
 'platinum': 185,
 'quantity': 1,
 'region': 'en',
 'user': {'avatar': 'user/avatar/5a3faf40c2c9e91d76478890.png?5ee0ca9b409cabc67edd44ebbaa60e56',
          'id': '5a3faf40c2c9e91d76478890',
          'ingame_name': 'CurryWaffle',
          'last_seen': '2018-06-02T18:24:00.836000+00:00',
          'region': 'en',
          'reputation': 7,
          'reputation_bonus': 0,
          'status': 'ingame'},
 'visible': True}
****************************************
# 5 ****************************************
Name xXfreakyXx
Status ingame
platinum 131
****************************************
RAW Document
****************************************
{'creation_date': 'iso',
 'id': '5b12d9dcc34b9200a9cd3236',
 'last_update': 'iso',
 'order_type': 'buy',
 'platform': 'pc',
 'platinum': 131,
 'quantity': 10,
 'region': 'en',
 'user': {'avatar': None,
          'id': '566c5dd0b66f836b34411fd9',
          'ingame_name': 'xXfreakyXx',
          'last_seen': '2018-06-02T18:22:08.374000+00:00',
          'region': 'en',
          'reputation': 0,
          'reputation_bonus': 0,
          'status': 'ingame'},
 'visible': True}
****************************************
```

**Dependencies:**

- http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Comment: Wow that works!!! Do you know how I could get the first 5 listings though?

Comment: The provided code already does this. It sorts the list by status: [online in game, online, offline] and returns first 5 from the top.

`limit = 5` - Means get first 5 from the top.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the first 5 on top of the page going from lowest price to highest when I run it and check the website too it gives me usernames that are way below 5 in the website

Answer (score 0):

This answer is regarding fetching the first 5 results of a sort (lowest to highest price).

Usually when you submit a filter or sort you can see how the URL reflects your search query. Pay attention to how the URL changes after you submit a sort (e.g. lowest-to-highest sort).

What you'll see will be similar to `http://www.example.com?sort=lowest`. The `?=sort=lowest` is called query parameters of a URL. You need to learn how to construct these query params in code. Then, the request you send using the `requests` library should be sent to these URLs that specify the sort you want. Once you have the sorted results, the code above will give you what you need.